# SSIS - How to manage authentication of dynamic connection manager?

Tags: ssis

I deployed a package which stores  db names and user roles of diffent servers. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srJau.png)

I set up the my source connection manager with specific username and pwd. But when i start the package then my connection manager always uses the windows authentication. 
I get the username and pwd from table and store them in the variables. Here is my dynamic connection manager properties window: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YA0yv.png)

I want to connect my servers with each username and pwd of them. Thanks for helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant tell from the image but I believe you have Integrated Security=SSPI in your expression. If you look at the connection string property you can see it on the end.  If you remove that it should use SQL login instead of Win Auth.